# After resolving conflicts, is it possible to continue a rebase without committing yet?

Tags: git, rebase, conflict

Do we need to commit the changes after resolving conflict during git rebase command? I am asking this because I do not want to commit yet because there can be a situation of more conflicts in later commits with git rebase --continue. So I want to resolve all the conflicts across multiple commits first and then commit. Please tell me is this possible or not?

Comment: Yes, you should do `git add .` to add how you resolved the whole conflicts, then go on `git rebase --continue`, you can still do `git rebase --abort` at some point. If you don't master what you're doing, I'd suggest to push your current branch (that way it's saved on the repository), try you git rebase locally, once done, check that everthing is fine, and `git push -f`, if it's okay, if not, you can still delete your LOCAL branch, and retrieve the remote one to start again.

Comment: but it means after git add ., need to commit them as well with git commit -m "message".  But I do not want to commit them now, because there are so many conflicts will come after git rebase --continue.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

You are describing a situation where you have multiple commits being rebased, and multiple commits have conflicts, and you're wondering if you can resolve multiple conflicts from multiple commits into a single commit. You can't do that, because when you rebase you are replaying each commit one at a time.

However, if you *could* do what you asked, then the end result would be fewer commits than you started with. If you're OK with that, then squash your commits into a fewer number *before* you begin the rebase (or "during" if you're using an interactive rebase). Then you will effectively achieve what you desired.

**Side Notes:**

1. In the worst case scenario, you can have a conflict on every commit you are rebasing. Squashing to fewer commits first reduces that worst case.
2. Sometimes, when you have many commits that you don't wish to squash along with conflicts at each commit, rebasing just isn't practical. In those cases you may be better off simply throwing in the towel and merging instead. With merge you can still have conflicts, but the worst case is just one set of conflicts to resolve, since you are only creating a single merge commit.